# Version control of data objects in Baqend

Tags: baqend

I see that data objects in the Baqend data storage are versioned.

Are the previous versions accessible?

Does the system store the ID of the user who wrote/updated the object?

Just curious what that is doing and if I need to try to create my own log or if there is something built in.

Specifically, I have "adminstrators" who will be manually verifying some data that is put into the database, then changing a specific field to "approved".  We to know the ID of the last person that modified the data.

Answer (score 1):

Baqend does not keep previous versions, and it only collects access logs. 
To save which user updated an object, you can use for example an [update handler](https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/baqend-code/#oninsert-and-onupdate) to save the user reference in your object.